# How to debug Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git" in a Jenkins job?

Tags: git, testing, jenkins

I'm using jenkins to build my git project, this is the error I am getting when see the log.
I am using git plugin in jenkins.

How would you troubleshoot that error message?

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace E:\sw\jenkins\workspace\se12
ERROR: Workspace has a .git repository, but it appears to be corrupt.
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree

org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1180)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1150)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1146)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:962)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:972)
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:651)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git" (in directory "E:\sw\jenkins\workspace\se12"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1169)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 22 more
    Cloning the remote Git repository
    Cloning repository $ git clone \\SE12\Adempiere370new\.git
    Fetching upstream changes from $ git clone \\SE12\Adempiere370new\.git
    ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: git fetch --tags --progress $ git clone \\SE12\Adempiere370new\.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1180)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1043)
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:651)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)

    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git" (in directory "E:\sw\jenkins\workspace\se12"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1169)
        ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you incorrectly set the git executable path.

It shouldn't be `C:\Program Files\Git`, but `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`
(this is similar to [JENKINS-6181](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6181))

[The Git plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) does mention:

> If you are seeing output indicating Git could not clone, something like the output below, go to to the **Jenkins configuration settings (not the project settings, the global ones)** and change the Git path to a fully qualified path (eg. not "`git`" but "`/usr/bin/git`" or wherever your Git binary is installed).

In your case, check that `C:\Program Files\Git` is indeed your Git installation path.

Comment: the above answer was helpful. But still 'does not appear to a git repository' problem still exists

Comment: @user3093983 that is for another question for you to ask.

Answer (score 1):

In your logs, looks like Jenkins agent doesn't have enough permissions to execute Git

```
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:651)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git" (in directory "E:\sw\jenkins\workspace\se12"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

Detail to

```
CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

For me the issue was different, it was

```
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Doing some research I came across this issue https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-12353

At the very bottom one guys says that the default PATH configuration in windows points to

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

When it should be

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

As I have jenkins agents in remote machines, I had to restart my agents to reload the PATH change in the host.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the git path correctly then only mention the path of git.exe else mention "git" in the URL .When it executes it checks on the jenkin sever PATH enviornment variable and find the git itself in one of the path.