# fatal: Could not read from remote repository.error in using jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, repository

I am using Jenkins to build from my git remote repository.
What am I suppose to provide in the repo url field since I am using remote local system for cloning and building.
Last time I give the clone command in the field and I got the error:

```
stderr: fatal: '//se12/adempiere370new' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I actually suppose to give in the url field?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "remote local system"? Could you explain what you mean by that? Usually it will be the same as you have as remote in your local repo `git remote -v`, i.e  git@github.com:user/repo-name.git

Comment: I mean local repository ie server is a local system in network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the user running the Jenkins Job has the right to access the remote folder which represents your remote repo monitored by Jenkins.

If you are on Windows (as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22005344/6309) tends to indicate), the path should be:

```
\\se12\adempiere370new
```

So make sure the user running Jenkins can do a `dir \\se12\adempiere370new`

The [OP Tony Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3093983/tony-davis) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008186/fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository-error-in-using-jenkins/22008843?noredirect=1#comment33366372_22008843) `//se12/adempiere370new` works too, but the command must be `git clone //se12/adempiere370new`, without any '`$`' in front of it.

Comment: The local system and jenkins can access the specified directory. But how can I check if jenkins can access it if not how can I provide access right?

Comment: @user3093983 The dir I mention is enough to check if Jenkins can access it. Try setting in your field `\\se12\adempiere370new` instead of `//se12/adempiere370new`

Comment: Still the same error occurs. The only problem is with the repo url. I can't solve it.

Comment: I can access //se12/adempiere370new but while trying to build using jenkins the same error occurs 'failed to fetch from //se12/adempiere370new' and 'fatal: '\se12\adempiere370new' does not appear to be a git repository'

Comment: @user3093983 Does Jenkins runs with the system account or a user account?

Comment: How can I check that? I just installed jenkins as given in tutorial and I am new to jenkins.

Comment: @TonyDavis to check: http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.fr/2012/08/running-jenkins-in-windows-with-regular.html Then http://stackoverflow.com/a/6694060/6309

Comment: I check the sites and changed to a user. while giving url as //se12/adempiere370new it shows an error message. $ sign in the beginning removes the error.

Comment: @TonyDavis Do you mean `$//se12/adempiere370new`?

Comment: No its now OK. Now timeout happens

Comment: @TonyDavis so where did you put '$' in order to remove the error?

Comment: while providing //se12/adempiere370new it shows an error like cannot connect remote repository. But now it is OK. At that time I provide $gitclone //se12/adempiere370new and the error goes. But now //se12/adempiere370new works fine.

Comment: @TonyDavis ok, so you mean making the git command *without* the '$' sign made it work. Got It.